# Llamar un método con un Thread

Tags: c#

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2015, SQL Compact Edition, WPF. Cargo una lista de datos con un método, este método lo quiero llamar desde un hilo, pero cuando lo implemento con el hilo no se ejecuta y pasa a la siguiente línea de código.

Sin thread

```
var listMov = SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal();
```

Con thread

```
if (KSensor != null)
        {
            int itemCount = 0;
            string line;
            string gestureName = String.Empty;

            ArrayList frames = new ArrayList();
            double[] items = new double[12];

            dtwTextOutput.Text = string.Empty;
            //var listMov = SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal();
            new Thread(() => { Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; var listMov = SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal(); }).Start();


            foreach (var mov in listMov)
            {
                gestureName = mov.Nombre; //Nombre del movimiento.
                dtwTextOutput.Text = dtwTextOutput.Text + mov.Nombre + "\r\n";
                var listDetMov = SdDetalleMovimiento.ListaDetalleMovimiento(mov.MovimientoCorporalId);
                foreach (var det in listDetMov)
                {
                    line = det.FotoGrama;
                    dtwTextOutput.Text = dtwTextOutput.Text + det.FotoGrama + "\r\n";

                    if (line.StartsWith("~"))
                    {
                        frames.Add(items);
                        itemCount = 0;
                        items = new double[12];
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!line.StartsWith("----"))
                    {
                        items[itemCount] = Double.Parse(line);
                    }

                    itemCount++;

                    if (line.StartsWith("----"))
                    {
                        _dtw.AddOrUpdate(frames, gestureName);
                        frames = new ArrayList();
                        gestureName = String.Empty;
                        itemCount = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            //_video = new ArrayList();
        }
```

En la línea de código que esta implementado el hilo no me pobla la lista porque nunca fue a la base de datos a traer la información por que se paso al ForEach.
¿Cuál es el problema?

Saludos!!!

Comment: El problema es que para eso se lanza un thread, para que haga trabajo en paralelo. O sea que no hay garantía que lo que se ejecute en el thread vaya a ejecutarse antes de que llegues al foreach. ¿Puedes explicar por qué quieres usar un thread? Creo que al entender tu objetivo, se te puede recomendar una alternativa que sea mas adecuada.

Comment: De hecho, agregaría que no entiendo cómo tu código compila. No lo veo válido que el foreach use `listMov` cuando este está definido dentro del lambda para el thread. ¿Seguro no tienes otro `listMov` definido globalmente? Si no, ¿compila este programa siquiera?

Comment: @sstan Es verdad compilaba porque tenia declarado a nivel de View el listMov pero igual le quite el var al hilo `new Thread(() => { Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; listMov = SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal(); }).Start();` igual no funciona.

Comment: No funciona por la primero que te deje, o sea, por el hecho que el thread trabaja en paralelo, es muy muy probable que el foreach se ejecute antes de que complete tu thread. La pregunta clave es, ¿por qué deseas usar un hilo? Es porque la consulta BD toma demasiado tiempo y quieres que tu interfaz no se congele? O hay otra razón? La respuesta de Einer asume que es por la primera razón (aunque su respuesta usa una técnica un poco anticuada). Si contestas la pregunta que te hago, voy a ver si dejo una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @sstan Respondiendo a tu pregunta, lo que pasa es que trabajo con un dispositivo que se llama Kinect el cual la cámara siempre esta tomando datos y cuando cargo los movimientos que están en la base de datos a la lista cuando alguien esta frente al dispositivo se congela la imagen y ese es solo una porque uso dos controles Image en uno sirve como cámara y en otro trabaja la cámara de profundidad que esta mostrando imagen esos dos controles con el canvas se congelan hasta que cargue la lista.

Comment: Correcto. Entonces la respuesta de Einer te puede servir. Voy a agregar una respuesta como alternativa en un momento.

Comment: @sstan Estaré a la expectativa.

Comment: @sstan Una consulta ¿es complicado usar thread? hay desarrolladores que prefieren usar task, te hago la pregunta ya que es la primera vez que implemento un thread y me encontré con esos comentarios.

Comment: Escribir código multi hilos es sumamente dificil de lograr correctamente. Son muy pocos que lo logran en realidad. Hay demasiadas maneras de que te salga mal. Por eso es mejor evitar usar la clase `Thread`, que es de muy bajo nivel, a menos que seas un experto, y son pocos de verdad que lo son. El task es un poco mas sencillo de usar, aunque todavía, hasta .NET 4.0, era un poco complicado y feíto. A partir de .NET 4.5 se introdujo simplificaciones con `async-await` y con `Task.Run`, lo que permite usar los tasks de una forma mas sencilla. Pero aun así, siempre hay que tener cuidado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya se tocó en los comentarios, cuando lanzas un thread con `thread.Start()`, no existe ninguna garantía de cuando se va a ejecutar ese thread. De modo que si tienes más código que se ejecuta después de esa sentencia, es sumamente probable que este se ejecute aun antes que el thread tenga la oportunidad de arrancar.

En tu caso, en los comentarios especificastes tu objetivo al tratar de usar el hilo. Se trata de evitar que se congele tu interfaz mientras se ejecuta la consulta a la base de datos.

Técnicamente, para lograr tu objetivo, ni siquiera necesitas un Task o hilo adicional. Si usas EF por ejemplo, este tiene la habilidad de ejecutar consultas a la base de datos de forma asincrona que sería lo ideal. Pero tengo entendido que con SQL Compact Edition, esta opción no existe.

Por esta razón, el uso de un task es adecuado tal como lo describe la respuesta de Einer. Sin embargo, a partir de C# 5/.NET 4.5, que parece que lo tienes, se introdujo una nueva sintaxis del `async-await` que permite el uso de tasks de una forma simplificada que permite leer el código casi como si no fuera asincrona, sin call backs, etc.

En tu caso, simplificando tu código un poco, quedaría de esta manera:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ...

private async void TuEventHandler() // nota el keyword async
{
    // ...

    // nota el keyword await
    var listMov = await Task.Run(() => SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal());

    foreach (var mov in listMov)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Aunque el async-await es un tema amplio, y que vale la pena que investigues porque te va a servir, los puntos claves del código arriba son:

- El `Task.Run()` ejecuta la consulta en un thread distinto.
- El `await` hace que tu código espere que el task complete antes de continuar, pero mientras espera, el UI thread queda libre, lo que evita que se congele tu interfaz.
- Cuando el task completa, el código que sigue al `await` se ejecuta en el UI thread.
- El `async` en la declaración del método es necesario para que puedas usar el keyword `await` dentro del método.

Pero aparte de esos detalles, notarás que el código se ve casi idéntico a la versión sin multi hilos.

Comment: sstan, que poderoso es async/await, de verdad tengo que estudiarlo había escuchado de ello pero nunca lo implemente, muchas gracias por la cátedra. Mejoro el performace de la app.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta utilizando [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) para ejecutar tu metodo de modo asincrono y luego obtenes el resultado utilizando el metodo `ContinueWith<TResult>`:

```
int itemCount = 0;
string line;
string gestureName = String.Empty;

ArrayList frames = new ArrayList();
double[] items = new double[12];

dtwTextOutput.Text = string.Empty;
//var listMov = SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal();

new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<ListMovivientoTemporal>(()=> SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal())
.ContinueWith((task)=>{

    var listMov = task.Result;
     foreach (var mov in listMov)
    {
        gestureName = mov.Nombre; //Nombre del movimiento.
        dtwTextOutput.Text = dtwTextOutput.Text + mov.Nombre + "\r\n";
        var listDetMov = SdDetalleMovimiento.ListaDetalleMovimiento(mov.MovimientoCorporalId);
        
        //codigo que sigue al foreach
        //...
    }
    
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Esto lo que hace es simple. Cuando el metodo `SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal()` returna resultados, se ejecuta el codigo que esta especificando en el delegado que se le envia al metodo `ContinueWith`. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` indica que utilize el `TaskScheduler` de la vista. en palabras simples: que utilize el hilo de la vista para actualizar los controles de la vista.

---

Noto que en tu codigo estas haciendo la logica mal. En esta linea de codigo:

```
    new Thread(() => { Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; var listMov = SdMovimientoCorporal.ListaMovimientoCorporal(); }).Start();
```

Estas ejecutando un nuevo hilo y declarando una variable local llamada `listMov` que no es visible fuera del delegado del hilo.

Otra cosa es que en tu implementacion no tienes en cuenta que el hilo puede tardar mas en ejecutarte que el resto del programa, por lo que al llegar al `foreach`, el hilo todavia no ha terminado para utilizar el valor de la variable en el foreach.

Comment: Einer, ¿tengo que crear una lista MovimientoTemporal?, así es tienes razón estaba mal implementado en el nuevo hilo usando un `var listMov` quedaba esa variable inaccesible al resto del código

Comment: La lista que tendria la informacion de los movimiento eostaria en la propiedd tas.Result. Lo agregue a una lista para que sepas que significa Result.